# Delete user in iOS using Parse login

Tags: ios, swift, parse-platform, authentication

I'm implementing parse login in iOS using swift. From a login view controller i get new users to signup via swift using just email and password. This creates a PFUser which correctly saves to Parse backend. The user is then taken to a UserDetails view controller to "complete" their signup by providing more details which gets saved to coredata (im using parse functionality just for the signup). If the user cancels however before "completing" the additional details, I want to delete the PFUser from parse created possibly moments earlier. In the UserDetails view controller under cancelTapped ibaction im running code

```
            if PFUser.currentUser() != nil {
            PFUser.currentUser()?.deleteInBackgroundWithBlock({ (deleteSuccessful, error) -> Void in
                print("success = \(deleteSuccessful)")
            })

            //user deleted in background block above but still logged in so now logout
            PFUser.logOut()
        }
```

but im getting following parse error [Error]: User cannot be deleted unless they have been authenticated. (Code: 206, Version: 1.8.5)  .... i dont know what authentication process is needed and im guessing the problem could be because im trying to delete a user before parse has had a proper time to create the user in the first place .... any help or suggestions appreciated

Comment: Can you provide your sign up code?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

User ALC permission automatically blocks anyone else from performing a write/delete on your record. This means you must be logged in if you want to update/delete your own record. In your code, you probably log out before your asynchronous delete code gets a chance to run in the background. Instead you need to log the user out after the delete was successful in the completion block of `deleteInBackgroundWithBlock` function.

```
if PFUser.currentUser() != nil {
        PFUser.currentUser()?.deleteInBackgroundWithBlock({ (deleteSuccessful, error) -> Void in
            print("success = \(deleteSuccessful)")
            PFUser.logOut()
        })         
}
```